# Symfony 2.4 - Profiler - No timing events have been recorded

Tags: symfony, timer, profiler, timeline

I tried to display my timeline in the symfony's profiler, but it keeps saying:

> "No timing events have been recorded. Are you sure that debugging is
>   enabled in the kernel?"

All debug, are activated in the kernel, and I do not see anything about "time event" in the documentation.

Somebody knows how to configure it properly?

Comment: Someone found the problem ?